# Error on my drupal website?

Tags: drupal-7

Hi everyone I have developed an drupal website but when it loads the website at the bottom there is an error occuring in the site.

**Error:
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.**

But when i refresh it again the error goes away.

What is the solution to avoid the error when the website loads for the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please search before you post a question. Adding a link which has already answered this question

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49905/the-website-encountered-an-unexpected-error-please-try-again-later